# How to write RegExp in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using the RegExp for my project successfully in Android by using the expression

```
^[(b|B)][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9]{5}$
^[(y|Y)][a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

& so i tried to use the same in flutter as

```
r'(b|B)[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9]{5}$'
r'(y|Y)[a-zA-Z]\d[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$'
```

but was not getting successful. Is there anything i have missed?

Comment: Is an error shown? What kind is it, syntax or an exception?

Comment: Its not showing any error, but i feel the syntax is wrong which I'm using

Comment: The Flutter RegExps you wrote are not the same as the ones used by Android (there is an extra `\d` in both of the Flutter RegExps).

Answer (score 0):

In dart you use the `RegExp` class: `RegExp exp = RegExp(r"...")`.

To get all matches with a `String str` just create an iterable of matches with your string: `Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(str);`

Refer to [RegExp-class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isValidEmail = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(this);
```